# Proof of the Uniqueness Part of Hensel's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Hensel's Lemma**: Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x], a \in \mathbb{Z}, k \geq 1.$ If $f(a) \equiv 0$ (mod $p$) and $f'(a) \not \equiv 0$ (mod $p$), then there exists a unique $b$ (mod $p^k$) such that $f(b) = 0$ (mod $p^k$) and $b \equiv a$ (mod $p$).

Much of the proof as to existence can be found [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf) (pp.2-3). One proceeds by induction on $k \geq 1.$ One assumes the inductive hypothesis, that there is a unique root $b_k$ (mod $p^k$) satisfying $f(b_k) = 0 \bmod p^k$ and $b_k \equiv a \bmod p$. To show the $k+1$th case holds, one defines \begin{align} b_{k+1} = b_k + p^kt_k \tag{1} \end{align}, where $t_k$ is the *unique* solution (mod $p$) to
\begin{align} 
f'(b_k)t_k \equiv -f(b_k)/p^k \bmod p. \tag{2} 
\end{align}
Using assumptions and the identity that $f(a + p^kt) = f(a) + f'(a)p^kt \bmod p^{k+1}$, for any $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, one can argue that a unique solution mod $p$ to (2) indeed exists and that $b_{k+1} \bmod p^{k+1}$ indeed satisfies $f(b_{k+1}) = 0 \bmod p^{k+1}$ and $b_{k+1} \equiv a \bmod p$.

I am having trouble, however, constructing the proof as to uniqueness of the Hensel's Lemma, as it is given above. The [link](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf) given before gives a proof of uniqueness to a slightly more difficult version of Hensel's Lemma, which does not apply to the statement above. How might I prove uniqueness for this version of Hensel's Lemma?

**Edit:** In following their reasoning for the uniqueness part on p.3, I write
\begin{align}
b_{k+1}' = b_{k+1} + p^{k}\gamma_k, \gamma_k \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}. 
\end{align}
Then, I use
\begin{align}
f(b_{k+1}') = f(b_{k+1} + p^{k+1} \gamma_{k}) = f(b_{k+1}) + f'(b_{k+1})p^{k}\gamma_{k} \bmod p^{k+1}.
\end{align}
By assumption, $f(b_{k+1}') = f(b_{k+1}) \equiv 0 \bmod p^{k+1}$. Thus, $f'(b_{k+1})\gamma_k \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Since $f'(b_{k+1}) \equiv f'(a) \neq 0 \bmod p$, I have $\gamma_k \equiv 0 \bmod p$... and this implies $b_{k+1}' \equiv b_{k+1} \bmod p^{k+1}$?

Comment: How is the uniqueness statement you cited more difficult than the uniqueness statement that you want?  Your version uses only integral coefficients rather than $p$-adic integer coefficients, but the math in both cases seems to be nearly the same since integers mod $p^k$ and $p$-adic integers mod $p^k$ are naturally isomorphic rings. In other words, if you just run through the argument at the link with integers in place of $p$-adic integers, where do you find yourself running into trouble?

Comment: The details in the edit you added at the end provide exactly the argument that was intended. Also there is another, arguably more elementary, way to approach the uniqueness mod $p^n$ of the root: during the induction argument in the proof,  prove along the way that for each $n \geq 1$, $f(x)$ has a unique root $a_n \bmod p^n$ such that $a_n \equiv a \bmod p$. I have expanded the remark right after the proof to point this out.

Comment: @KCd Thank you for this. Just one point of clarification: Does the relation $b_{k+1}' = b_{k+1} + p^k\gamma_{k}$ hold because both $b_{k+1}', b_{k+1}$ are of the form (1)?

Comment: That's just an inductive assumption.  When $k \geq 1$ we assume there is a unique root mod $p^k$ that reduces to $a \bmod p$, so this holds automatically at $k = 1$, and then show when there is a unique root mod $p^k$ that there is a unique root mod $p^{k+1}$.  Thus the relation you ask about is simply a consequence of  (i) there being a unique root mod $p^k$ that's $a \bmod p$ and (ii) any root mod $p^{k+1}$ that is $a \bmod p$ reduces to a root mod $p^k$ that is $a \bmod p$.

Answer (score -1):

Hints:

- Take two solutions $b$ and $c$.
- It is clear that $b \equiv c \bmod p$.
- Prove by induction that $b \equiv c \bmod p^j$ for $j\le k$.